# How bootstrap sampling cause bias in Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest, bootstrap, importance

I am confused how bootstrap sampling causes bias in the feature selection process of Random Forest.

In this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186%2F1471-2105-8-25#enumeration), it says "Obviously, the bootstrap sampling artificially induces an association between the variables.". Could you please further explain how bootstrap sampling causes bias and why?

Comment: Maybe it was meant that repeating samples will overinflate an already present correlation, or that different bootstrap samples may introduce new correlations, that were not present in the originial sample.

Comment: I added the [tag:importance] tag, because this and Strobl's related work is all in the context of variable importance measures for random forests.